# Classification with numerical label?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, regression, data-mining, rapidminer

I know of a couple of classification algorithms such as decision trees, but I can't use any of them to the problem I have at hands.

I have a dataset in which each row contains information about a purchase. It's columns are:

```
- customer id
- store id where the purchase took place
- date and time of the event
- amount of money spent
```

I'm trying to make a prediction that, given the information of who, where and when, predicts how much money is going to be spent.

What are some possible ways of doing this? Are there any well-known algorithms?

Also, I'm currently learning RapidMiner, and I'm experimenting with some of its features. Everything that I've tried there doesn't allow me to have a real number (amount spent) as a label. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: What you are trying to do is not classification but regression. I suggest you do some further research into what regression is. To get you started, look into "linear regression".

Comment: I agree with Robin that regression is the normal approach to model continues numerical values.  But for the given problem a classification approach could also be feasible. What you could try is not to model the exact amount of money spend, but predict a range of prices (e.g. high, low, medium). For this you can use the binning operators in RapidMiner and then use a classifier operator.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Decision Tree Regressor for this. Using a toolkit like scikit-learn, you could use the DecisionTreeRegressor algo where your features would be store id, date and time, and customer id, and your target would be the amount spent.

You could turn this into a supervised learning problem. This is untested code, but it could probably get you started

```
# Load libraries
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn import grid_search

def fit_predict_model(data_import):
    """Find and tune the optimal model. Make a prediction on housing data."""

    # Get the features and labels from your data
    X, y = data_import.data, data_import.target

    # Setup a Decision Tree Regressor
    regressor = DecisionTreeRegressor()
    parameters = {'max_depth':(4,5,6,7), 'random_state': [1]}

    scoring_function = metrics.make_scorer(metrics.mean_absolute_error, greater_is_better=False)
    ## fit your data to it ##
    reg = grid_search.GridSearchCV(estimator = regressor, param_grid = parameters, scoring=scoring_function, cv=10, refit=True)
    fitted_data = reg.fit(X, y)

    print "Best Parameters: "
    print fitted_data.best_params_

    # Use the model to predict the output of a particular sample
    x = [## input a test sample in this list ##]
    y = reg.predict(x)
    print "Prediction: " + str(y)

fit_predict_model(##your data in here)
```

I took this from a project I was working on almost directly to predict housing prices so there are probably some unnecessary libraries and without doing validation you have no clue how accurate this case would be, but this should get you started.

Check out this link:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as comments have pointed out it's regression that you need.  Linear regression does sound like a good starting point as you don't have a huge number of variables.

In RapidMiner type regression into the Operators menu and you'll see several options under Modelling-> Functions.  Linear Regression, Polynomical, Vector, etc.  (There's more, but as a beginner let's start here). 
Right click any of these operators and press Show Operator Info and you'll see numerical labels are allowed.
Next scroll through the help documentation of the operator and you'll see a link to a tutorial process. It's really simple to use, but it's good to get you started with an example.

Let me know if you need any help.